# Use output value in terraform object

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, terraform-provider-aws

I have multiple output variable, I want to make one parent out variable and then put other outputs into it. I have searched about it and found that we can user terraform object for it but can't get the syntax right.
Output.tf

```
output "public_subnet" {
  value = "${module.my_vpc.public_subnets_ids}"
}
output "vpc_id" {
  value = "${module.my_vpc.vpc_id}"
}
output "private_subnet" {
  value = "${module.my_vpc.private_subnets_ids}"
}
```

I want my output to be in a object or you can say parent output variable that have all child output vales, I have come up with few line which I know is not right syntax wise but will get you a picture of what I am thinking of.

```
output "vpc" {
  value = {
    vpc_id         = "${module.my_vpc.vpc_id}"
    public_subnet  = "${module.my_vpc.public_subnets_ids}"
    private_subnet = "${module.my_vpc.private_subnets_ids}"
  }
  type = object({ vpc_id = string, public_subnet = string, private_subnet = string })
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Terraform [output](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html) does not have `type`. Therefore, your `vpc` should be:

```
output "vpc" {
  value = {
    vpc_id         = "${module.my_vpc.vpc_id}"
    public_subnet  = "${module.my_vpc.public_subnets_ids}"
    private_subnet = "${module.my_vpc.private_subnets_ids}"
  }  
}
```

But the issue is that a child module has **no access to its parrent's outputs.** Thus, I'm not exactly sure what do you want to achieve with your outputs. Normally, you would pass variables from parent to child using `variable`, and then you could make new output from those variables in the child module.

#### Update

Based on your previous questions, there is `main.tf` with

```
module "my_vpc" {
  source            = "./modules/vpc"
  vpc_cidr          = var.vpc_cidr
  public_subnet     = var.public_subnet
  private_subnet    = var.private_subnet
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names
}
```

Therefore, you must have a folder `./modules/vpc`. In the folder, there may be a file called `./modules/vpc/vpc.tf`. The file will have something like this in it (variables could be in separate file as well):

```
variable "vpc_cidr" {}

variable "public_subnet" {}

variable "private_subnet" {}

variable "availability_zone" {}

# the rest of the VPC definition. Since the file is not given,
# i can only speculate on the exact details of the content

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {

  count  = length(var.public_subnet)

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  # other attributes
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private" {

  count  = length(var.private_subnet)

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  # other attributes
}
```

If so, then you can create a new file, called `./modules/vpc/output.tf` with the content:

```
output "vpc" {
  value = {
    vpc_id         = my_vpc.vpc_id
    public_subnet  = aws_subnet.public.*.id
    private_subnet = aws_subnet.private.*.id
  }  
}
```

Comment: how can you do it with terraform object?

Comment: @Shifa Hi. Can you clarify "do it?" Do what?

Comment: Hi Marcin, my supervisor asked me to use terraform object in the output.tf file https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/types.html so that if I want to reference to the output i can just use `"${module.vpc.vpc_id}"` `"${module.vpc.public_subnet}"` like the name of the output variable remains the same and we can access different attributes like `vpc_id` `public_subnet` etc

Comment: Did you get my point? I did alot of search and didn't find any useful material

Comment: @Shifa I'm trying to piece the puzzle. I remember the VPC from yesterday. I think I know what you mean. Give me few minutes to verify.